# Why firstname and lastname fields are stored after fail validation which password doesn't

Tags: django

I have a registration form there are have few fields including first name, last name, password and password confirm. I'm wondering why first name and last name value still in the form after the form fail in validation while password field doesn't. What makes those fields behave differently from each other.

Comment: Can I ask you what do you expecting to happen when the form validation failure?

Comment: I have another field and it lost data after validation failure like password field. I want to keep store the value in that field like first name and last name field.